# Query the local_size values declared in a shader

Tags: opengl, glsl

OpenGL Compute Shader declare their expected workGroup size using local_size lines like those

```
layout (local_size_x = 128, local_size_y = 1, local_size_z = 1) in;
```

later, the C++ program that executes the shader whould call the glDispatchCompute

```
glDispatchCompute(numWorkItems / workGroupSize, 1, 1);
```

where workGroupSize should be exactly 128 or else bad things are going to happen. This mean that modifying the shader source needs to modify the also the C++.

The question is if there a way to query the which are the values declared in the shader after it has been compiled and linked into a glProgram. Of course, I know the GLuint values used in the call to `glAttachShader(programID, shaderID);` function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```c
GLint local_size[3];
glGetProgram(program, GL_COMPUTE_WORK_GROUP_SIZE, &local_size);
```

(https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glGetProgram.xhtml)